# Is it better to deposit your salary into you checking or savings account?

Tags: salary

What are the pros and cons of having a direct deposit from a paycheck going into a checking account vs. a savings account?

Comment: The question as is stands is too broad, and the answers would apply for _any_ deposit, not just salary.

Comment: country? there may be rules associated with the accounts. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, it is better to deposit into a checking or savings account than to get cash.

Comment: @HartCO - Hah. That is an awesome comment (to the question as originally worded).

Answer (score 7):

If you're in the United States, it may be better to deposit your paycheck into your checking account. Savings accounts have a statutory limit on the number of outgoing transfers per month you're allowed to make. Checking accounts generally don't have such restrictions.

These restrictions could impact you if, for example, your paycheck is deposited into your savings account and you need to make transfers out of that account to pay bills. You could potentially hit the transfer limit and have difficulty accessing your money. If, on the other hand, your paycheck is deposited into your checking account, you can pay bills and make as many transfers as you want.

Comment: Or you could deposit into the savings account, then make one lump-sum transfer into checking to pay bills &c.  Though I prefer deposit into checking myself.  Savings is just a sort of quick-access emergency fund.